# Regex for search queries

Tags: regex, django

I have page designed in Django that has its own search engine. What I need help with is construction of regex that will filter only valid queries, which are consisting only of polish alphabet letters(both upper- and lowercase) and symbols * and ? , can anyone be of assistance?

EDIT:
I tried something like that:

```
query_re = re.compile(r'^\w*[\*\?]*$', re.UNICODE)
if not query_re.match(self.cleaned_data['query']):
    raise forms.ValidationError(_('Illegal character'))
```

but it also allows some invalid characters from different alphabets and wont allow *somest?ing* queries.

Comment: How about presenting one of your approaches? Or some code snippets where you tried something? That would be helpful...

Comment: Put the \w inside the [], and use re.LOCALE instead of re.UNICODE. Then you have essentially the same regex I gave in my answer below.

Comment: When I use re.LOCALE Polish letters are invalid, but when I use re.UNICODE they are valid, but letters from other alphabets are valid too as well as brackets '[]' and probably more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
regex = r'(?iL)^[\s\*\?a-z]*$'
```

assuming your machine's locale is Polish. The first part (?iL) sets the [locale and ignorecase flags](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#compilation-flags). The ^ matches the start of the string, \s matches any whitespace, and a-z any lowercase letter (or uppercase, thanks to the ignorecase flag).

Alternatively, instead of using (?L) and a-z, you could just explicitly list the allowable letters (e.g. abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz).

Comment: Thanks for swift reply. Unfortunately this doesn't work, Polish letters are still considered invalid, machine locale is set correctly getlocale returns: ('pl_PL', 'UTF8'). I tried the a-z and aąbcćdeę... variants but still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

If your locale is correctly set, you would use

```
query_re = re.compile(r'^[\w\*\?]*$', re.LOCALE|re.IGNORECASE)
```

`\w` matches all locale-specific alphanumerics: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: Other than using \w instead of a-z and splitting the flags out to be part of compilation instead of inline, how is this different from my answer?

Comment: presumably using `\w` instead of `[a-z]` allows the regex engine to leverage to locale's understanding of what is a word character?  If so, this is a much better answer!